# Which font is used for this "haiku"?

Tags: font-identification, serif

I believe this font will be a good fit for my cover magazine layout I'm trying to pull of right. I used all of those font-identification websites but none was correct.

[image: haiku]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to discern all of the exact details from the image provided, but I'd say that's Palatino:

[image]

Comment: It might be horizontally stretched Palatino. The cross bar on the "t" looks thicker in the example.